# cant find directory of action in form

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

I have custom module in my magento store that create a form in frontend
I want to find out the form posting variables to where so when i inspecting form  the action shows this:(i am working on localhost)

> http://127.0.0.1/myproject/index.php/marketplace/seller/save/

i cant recognize where it point to??
thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your post i would like to give an answer consideration of `Apptha_Marketplace` extension, i hope this information is useful for you.

`Marketplace:` is a front name of the marketplace module

`Seller:` is a controller (SellerController.php)

`Save:` is an action (saveAction method available in SellerController.php)

Kindly check the file paths like below:

1. `app/code/local/Apptha/Marketplace/controllers/SellerController.php` => there is a `public function saveAction{}` just keep magento **Mage::log** and  so that u can find easily whether this method is calling or not.

   `Mage::log('Your save action has been callineg', null, 'custom.log');`
2. If file not found please check the same in the `community Pool`.

Comment: you are welcome @mohsne.MY . Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

As unsure to which module you are using I cannot be sure on path but most likely going to be

```
app/code/community/VendorName/ModuleName/controllers/seller.php
```

Or

```
app/code/local/VendorName/ModuleName/controllers/seller.php
```

And the function you are looking for is  saveAction